# How do I extract the result value out of a Prometheus query in Golang?

Tags: go, prometheus, promql, minio

Using these packages:

```
"github.com/prometheus/client_golang/api"
v1 "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/api/prometheus/v1"
```

I am running `minio_cluster_usage_total_bytes{job=1}` via Query:

```
promAPI := v1.NewAPI(client)
promquery := fmt.Sprintf("minio_cluster_usage_total_bytes{job=\"1\"}")

res, _, err := promAPI.Query(context.Background(), promquery, time.Now())
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

Printing the response, via `log.Println(res.String())` and `log.Println(res.Type())` shows this:

```
2024/03/05 11:16:08 minio_cluster_usage_total_bytes{instance="", job="1", server="127.0.0.1:9000"} => 18429647893 @[1709658968.29]
2024/03/05 11:16:08 vector
```

How can I extract *just* the resulting value, i.e. 18429647893 in this case? I would very much prefer to avoid string parsing functions if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's a little gnarly but the documentation helps uncover the solution.

[`API`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/client_golang@v1.19.0/api/prometheus/v1#API) `Query` method returns types that implement an interface [`model.Value`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/common/model#Value)

`model.Value` implementing types require a `Type` method that returns [`ValueType`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/common/model#ValueType)

Your code should switch over these values but, in this case it will be `ValVector`

You can type assert `res` to [`model.Vector`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/common@v0.48.0/model#Vector) which is an alias for `[]*Sample` (where [`Sample`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/common@v0.48.0/model#Sample) and has fields including `Value` and `Timestamp`)

In your case, I think you'll have a single `[]*Sample` entry but, for consistency, I've interated over the slice.

So:

```golang
switch res.Type() {
case model.ValScalar:
    // Implement model.Scalar
case model.ValVector:
    vector := res.(model.Vector)
    for _, sample := range vector {
        log.Println(sample.Value)
    }
case model.ValMatrix:
    // Implement model.Matrix
case model.ValString:
    // Implemenet String
}
```